# Android Webview Wont Load Subdomain

Tags: java, android, webview

Yes, you read the title correclty the behavior im seeing is that this will successfully work (render a web view):

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
```

While this will fail silently (it will create a new webview if you look at the remote devices tab but wont load the document or switch your app view to the webview)

```
myWebView.loadUrl("https://app.booksbnb.com/");
```

I've tried a few others and I'm guessing it's because of the subdomain?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I am still facing this issue, any help is appreciated